# php select from database and fill multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a point of sale project. I want on selecting a product echo the product price in another field. I cant find a way of doing it. here is my code

```
<?php
    include('../connect.php');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
    $result->execute();
?>
<form>
    <select>
    <?php
        for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>">
            <?php echo $row['product_code']; ?>
            - 
            <?php echo $row['gen_name'];  ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="qty"  min="1" placeholder="Qty" autocomplete="off" style="width: 68px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-     bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" / required>
    <input type="number" name="pc" max="25" placeholder="disc" autocomplete="off" style="width: 68px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" />
    <input type="number" name="price" max="25" value="price goes here "  style="width: 68px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('m/d/y'); ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there an error appearing?

Comment: I just noticed that you're binding a parameter not in the query.

Comment: Oh, and avoid using inline css especially if it's a lot

Comment: looking at your query you dont need this line `$result->bindParam(':userid', $res);`

Comment: Or maybe this should be `$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products where userid = :userid");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in a easy way using javascript, take a look in the example bellow, so you can echo the price anywhere that you want juse using the id or whatever that is good for you

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
var price = $(this).val();
var fruitName = $(this).find(":selected").text();

$("#fruitPrince").text('You choose '+fruitName+' and the price is: $'+price);

})
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <select class="form-control" id="mySelect">
  <option selected disabled> Choose a Fruit </option>
  <option value="10"> Banana </option>
  <option value="5"> Apple </option>
  <option value="3"> Orange </option>
  </select>
  <div class="bg-success">
    <p id="fruitPrince"> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

used Reynnan victor's example. it worked for me. here is the code

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$result->execute();
for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
?>
<option value="<?php
echo $row['price'];
?>" ><?php
echo $row['gen_name'];
?>
<?php
echo $row['product_code'];
?></option>
<?php
}
?></select>
<input type="number" name="qty"  min="1" placeholder="Qty" required/>
<text id="price" contenteditable="true" name="price"> 
 <script>$("#mySelect").change(function(){
var price = $(this).val();
$("#price").text(price);
})</script></text>
```